# Controller is ignoring data changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having some trouble with data being sent through my controller, here's a simplified example:

```
    public ActionResult EditNote(NotesModel model)
    {      
        model.Author = Session["UserName"].ToString();      
        model.Note = null;
        model.Title = null;
        return View(model);
    }
```

On my views page the data shown from the model is the exact same as how it was received by the method and all changes are ignored, why?

**Bigger picture:**

I'm trying to have a user edit an existing note in the database,  if they're the one who made it of course. based on whether or not they're the author they will either edit the existing note or create a new note, this is where the problem lies. The controller is supposed to set all the values of the model to null so that on the views page they will be empty.
Editing an existing note is no problem however emptying the model so the editing page is blank does not work.

**EDIT**

This is my view page:

```
@model WebsiteProject.Models.NotesModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
@section Sidebar
{
    <div id="sidebarheadericon" style="background-image: url('../Content/icons/apps.png')"></div>
    <div id="headertext"><h1>Welcome</h1></div>
    <hr id="seperator" />
    <p class="psidebar">test</p>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "EditNote")
    </p>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h1>NotesModel</h1>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <p class="control-label">Note by @Session["UserName"].ToString()</p>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Note, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="largebtn" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="text-danger">@ViewBag.NoteViewError</p>
</div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "NoteApp")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Here you can see the data that is received** (dummy data)
[image: Data received]

**Now here you'll see that the data of the model is changed**
[image: Data changed]

**Yet on the website it is not changed**
[image: Website]

The biggest problem isn't the Note and Title not being changed because the user can do that, but the Id and Author, which the user cannot, and should not be able to change.

Comment: It sounds like you may be making a mistake in your debugging.  Can you show the view for `EditNote`?  How specifically are you testing this and observing the result?

Comment: @David I've added more info and some images to hopefully help clarify the issue.

Comment: And this is *specifically* the `EditNote` view?  How *specifically* are you making the request to it?  When you place a debugging breakpoint in the view itself where the values are used, does the debugger stop on that line after `return View(model)`?  What are the observed values when the debugger reaches the view?

Comment: @David The view is specifically the EditNote view, this view is called from the ViewNote view via this line: 
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditNote", Model)

I cannot place a breakpoint on my views pages, am I supposed to?
I just noticed that if i do not return the model but just a blank: return View(); it still returns the original model.

Comment: It really sounds like you're making a mistake or false assumption in your debugging somewhere.  You definitely should be able to pause the Visual Studio debugger in a view on any line of C# code.  (Try on the `ViewBag.Title = "";` line, you can observe the value of `Model` from there.)  And passing a *null* model should *probably* result in an error.  (Which you can also force by trying to dereference any property on `Model` at the very beginning of the view.)  It's *extremely unlikely* that this fundamental feature of this framework is broken in such a blatant way.

Comment: @David I've managed to get a breakpoint on my views page but the Model just reads null.
I've been breaking my head over this for the last 7 days and it's driving me nuts I've rewritten my code several times tried different ways of doing this but i keep running into this issue for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried returning a copy of the model or a new object from the controller? This will help eliminate any issues with the debugging or state.

Comment: @Ceemah Four Yes i have, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the fact that you are using `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { htmlAttributes = ... })
```

It so happens that `EditorFor` not only uses the **`Model`** object, it also uses **`ModelState`** which keeps a copy of all values for all Model items that were received, parsed and validated, along with any validation errors that this may have produced.

As long as `ModelState` has a value for that model item, it will be shown by `EditorFor`. The reason is that user input may be invalid, like entering 12X for an `int` Model property. EditorFor will show 12X if the form is re-rendered, which is coming from ModelState, and which could never come from Model.

Unwanted values can be removed by calling [`Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.remove?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-modelstatedictionary-remove(system-string)), like this:

```
ModelState.Remove("Note");
```

On a different note, the ViewModel class that you are using here is *not suited to the needs of this action method*. It may be better to create a dedicated ViewModel class for it, with fewer properties, which you can then convert to the ViewModel type that the View needs.

Comment: Thank you, if only the many tutorials I've watched would have mentioned ModelState...
The code I've shown here is all simplified and cut down to highlight the problem, the ViewModel to my knowledge should be good as it is. (Unless I misunderstood what you are talking about).
Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to have prematurely accepted this as answer but unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

Comment: It sort of works.. ModelState.Clear() will clear the Model when it is called in the HttpGet method, but after submitting the form and the HttpPost method is called the ModelState is not cleared anymore and parts of the old data are back such as Id and Author.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to tell the incoming notes model is a new one or an existing one, here is some code to try,

```
public ActionResult EditNote(NotesModel model)
{
  if(model.Id > 0)  //assuming existing notes has id or any other ways you want to check
  {
    //save data
    return View(model);
  }
  else //if Id has a value <= 0, return a new model with only Author set, maybe the Id (depending on how you want to generate the Id)
  {
    var model = new NotesModel();
    model.Author = Session["UserName"].ToString(); 
    return Viwe(model);
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck here unfortunately..